# How to populate number of days in month right after selecting the month and year in Javascript/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is the code:

```
        <label for="birthday">Birthday Year</label>
        <select id="byear" name="byear" required>
            <option value="">Select Year</option>
            <?
            $fy = date("Y")-19;
            for ($i = $fy; $i >= date("Y")-80; $i--) {
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        <label for="birthday">Month</label>
        <select id="bmonth" name="bmonth" required>
            <option value="">Select Month</option>
            <option value="jan">January</option>
            <option value="feb">February</option>
            <option value="mar">March</option>
            <option value="apr">April</option>
            <option value="may">May</option>
            <option value="jun">June</option>
            <option value="jul">July</option>
            <option value="aug">August</option>
            <option value="sep">September</option>
            <option value="oct">October</option>
            <option value="nov">Novermber</option>
            <option value="dec">December</option>
        </select>


        <label for="birthday">Day</label>
        <select id="bday" name="bday" required disabled>
            <option value="">Select Day</option>
            <?
            $fm = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,month??,year??);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $fm; $i++) {
                echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Two questions:

- How can day listbox become enabled only when year and month are
  selected, and become disabled if one of them gets reset to null?
- How could function cal_days_in_month() take in directly the year and month selected in previous listboxes?

Comment: with some relatively straightforward JavaScript selection event handling. There are lots of premade libraries out there that you can use, have you tried any? And if not, why not?

Comment: This needs to be done in javascript but you haven't shown any javascript . Please show attempts made so it doesn't appear that you are expecting others to do your coding work for you

Comment: better way is to add a calendar to select a date.. jquery ui calendar is a better one.. https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should populate the bday select options with client-sided javascript, like in the snippet I made for you below. All you have to do is put your php that generates the year-options back in the example below (I can't put server-sided PHP in the example below). Enjoy!

Please note: this code will even automatically calculate the amount of days in each month! (February has 28, except in leap years, then it has 29!). Try February 1992 for example (that's a leap year).

```js
function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

$('#byear, #bmonth').change(function() {

  if ($('#byear').val().length > 0 && $('#bmonth').val().length > 0) {
    $('#bday').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#bday').find('option').remove();

    var daysInSelectedMonth = daysInMonth($('#bmonth').val(), $('#byear').val());

    for (var i = 1; i <= daysInSelectedMonth; i++) {
      $('#bday').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
    }

  } else {
    $('#bday').prop('disabled', true);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="birthday">Birthday Year</label>
<select id="byear" name="byear" required>
  <option value="">Select Year</option>
  <option value="1994">1994</option>
  <option value="1993">1993</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for="birthday">Month</label>
<select id="bmonth" name="bmonth" required>
  <option value="">Select Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">Novermber</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select><br><br>

<label for="birthday">Day</label>
<select id="bday" name="bday" required disabled>
  <option value="">Select Day</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using PHP here? What you want to achieve is easily done with a purely JS/Jquery solution.

There are jquery plugins that probably does everything you want already:
https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/calendar/

However, if you really want to do it yourself I'd change the HTML to this (gutting away all PHP):

```
 <label for="birthday">Birthday Year</label>
    <select id="byear" name="byear" onchange="generateDays(this)" required>
        <option value="">Select Year</option>

        /*you can hardcode the years here or just generate it with a js function*/
    </select>

    <label for="birthday">Month</label>
    <select id="bmonth" name="bmonth" onchange="generateDays(this)" required>
        <option value="">Select Month</option>
        <option value="jan">January</option>
        <option value="feb">February</option>
        <option value="mar">March</option>
        <option value="apr">April</option>
        <option value="may">May</option>
        <option value="jun">June</option>
        <option value="jul">July</option>
        <option value="aug">August</option>
        <option value="sep">September</option>
        <option value="oct">October</option>
        <option value="nov">Novermber</option>
        <option value="dec">December</option>
    </select>


    <label for="birthday">Day</label>
    <select id="bday" name="bday" required disabled>
       /* keep this empty */
    </select>
```

Then all you would need is a JS function:

```
function generateDays(sel) {
    var year = document.getElementById('byear').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('bmonth').value


    if(year == "" || month == "") {
       //disable your bday input or do whatever you want
       document.getElementById('bday').disabled = true;
    } else {

        var days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        //enable bday in case it was previously disabled
        document.getElementById('bday').disabled = false;

        //Clear the bday select element first
        document.getElementById('bday').innerHTML = "";

        for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
            document.getElementById('bday').innerHTML += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried it on jsfiddle, but for some readon the day listbox is always disabled

Comment: woops sorry about that, made a few typos in the code. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/eqffs/163/. Remember to set the js to No Wrap - in body in jsfiddle